# Mysql like Limit ( records ) in Dynamodb?

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-opsworks

I am using `aws PHP sdk` to querying `dynamodb`.

Requirement is to fetch records in a `batch of 10 items`. 
When user scroll screen down then fetch `10 previous items` and so on.

How can I instruct `Dynamodb` to fetch **only 10 items** ? I use `Limit option` but as per documentations of dynamodb `Limit` option is the `number of records to process` , not number of records **dynamodb** will return.

How can I give limit of number of records to return so that in next run I can use `LastEvaluatedKey` as `ExclusiveStartkey` for next 10.

Here is the snippet of my code

```
    // It means get the top $limit posts
    $iterator = $dynamo->query(array(
            'TableName'     => 'posts',
            'IndexName' => 'college_id-unix_timestamp-index',
            'ScanIndexForward' => false,
            'ExclusiveStartKey' => $lastEvaluatedKey,
            'KeyConditions' => array(
                'college_id' => array(
                    'AttributeValueList' => array(
                        array('S' => (string)$collegeId )
                    ),
                    'ComparisonOperator' => 'EQ'
                )

            ),

            'Limit' => (Integer)$limit,
        )

    );
```

Comment: I thought limit set the number of results I want to get then I get the LastEvaluatedKey and set it to 'ExclusiveStartKey' in next run to get 10 previous records with ScanForwardIndex==false